# Using VC++ to execute a shell extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm working on a function to convert input files for my app to .ly files for use with [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org).  What I would like to do in the conversion routine is go ahead and generate the PDF of the music.  If I were to do this myself, I would double click the .ly file or I would right click the file and select "Generate PDF."  I hoped that using ShellExecuteEx on the file would work the same as double clicking the file, but it doesn't.  Is there a way in VC++ (VStudio 2008) to execute the "Generate PDF" as found in the context menu in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the proper verb in the lpVerb member of the [SHELLEXECUTEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759784(VS.85).aspx) structure.

Here is how you [find the right verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776886(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: How do you determine the Class ID?

Comment: If it isn't your extension, you grep the registry looking for the DLL you think it lives in.  Or for the string on the context menu (don't forget the & in front of the shortcut key).